# PImage array - NullPointerException

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception, processing, sprite

For my current project, I'm creating a 2D fighting game using P3D, using sprites for the characters. While setting it up, I only am trying to display one character on screen, so my current setup is:

I have one parent class called 'Fighter', which contains values for the location in the world and booleans determining what the fighter is currently doing. Then I have class called 'Animation' which extends 'Fighter'. This is where the sprites are stored, and I think where the NPE originates. The class has a constructor where a larger PImage is cut up into smaller frames and stored in an array for each animation.

This larger PImage contains 192 frames. The game was originally based off of dragonball, so the plan was to have the character charge up and transform past a certain point - the 3 transformation groups are stored on top of each other on the sheet. Within those groups are the animation sets for actions - punching, kicking, idle, moving, etc. each collumn is a frame, and each animation contains four frames (4*16*3).

The trouble stems, I think, from cutting the larger PImage up and storing the individual frames for that animation within an array. I managed to get this working in an earlier version, but I used states, and stored the whole PImage (192 frames) within a single array, and called the rows by state. The end result of all that was that it took extremely long and complicated code to display 2 characters on screen, be it the same or different.

the entire sketch can be found here, images and all: https://mega.co.nz/#!kRYUBYbI!wNRvKNo54BpAc4QbWZpEuoHJoJJcBkGmRK9rSgoIGu4

or here is the Animation class, containing the code used to cut up the sprite sheet.

```java
class Animation extends Fighter {
  PImage [] playerFrames; 
  int count, currentFrame = 0; 


  Animation(int startX, int startY) { // constructor
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      playerFrames[x] = gokuSpriteSheet.get(x*90 + startX, startY, 90, 85);
    }
  } // Animation()

  int cx = (currentFrame == 4 ? 1 : currentFrame);

  void display() {

    if (count++ > 7) {
      count = 0;
      currentFrame++;
      if (currentFrame >= 4) 
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    image(playerFrames[cx], x, y); 
  } // void display()
}


class AnimationSet { 
  Animation idleRight = new Animation(0, 0);
  Animation idleLeft = new Animation(0, 85);
  Animation moveRight = new Animation(0, 170);
  Animation moveLeft = new Animation(0, 255);
  Animation jumpRight = new Animation(0, 340);
  Animation jumpLeft = new Animation(0, 425);
  Animation punchRight = new Animation(0, 510);
  Animation punchLeft = new Animation(0, 595);
  Animation kickRight = new Animation(0, 680);
  Animation kickLeft = new Animation(0, 765);
  Animation blockRight = new Animation(0, 850); 
  Animation blockLeft = new Animation(0, 935);
  Animation kiAtkRight = new Animation(0, 1020);
  Animation kiAtkLeft = new Animation(0, 1105);
  Animation chargeRight = new Animation(0, 1190);
  Animation chargeLeft = new Animation(0, 1275);
}

AnimationSet [] powerStates;
```

The ideal end result would be a sketch that starts up on a generic menu, allows you to select the world and yours/your opponents characters, and then finally creates all those objects once you click proceed. I'm still not familliar with certain techniques used in this language, so I don't think some of that will be possible, but I'm hoping to duplicate the animation class 4 times over for each character skin, then create a player and target object of each. I'll then create an integer, let you change it in the menu, and based on the selected choice, use if statements to run the object functions in draw.

So, finally, on to my question: 
How do I cut up the larger PImage I have and store 4 frames without invoking a NPE?
Do I need to change the sprite sheet itself into individual images of four frames for each action, and pass the filename of each as a string when the Animations are being constructed?
Any other suggestions for solutions, bearing in mind that I'm trying to display 2 characters on screen, from a selection of four (they can be the same)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, I did search around but nullPointerException strikes me as a very common and vague error, and I couldn't find an example that helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting the the PDE doesn't tell you where the NPE originated. You can determine it yourself by putting `print("got here")` calls around in your code to narrow it down, though. When I did this, I found that the line `player.func();` in your `draw()` was causing the error. In that method, you use the variable `powerStates`, which you (confusingly?) declared at the bottom of the `class_Animation` file, but you never gave it a value (eg `powerStates = something;`). When you declare but don't define an array of Objects, it fills the array with `null` values, so when you call something like `powerStates[SSJ].moveRight.display();`, it evaluates `powerStates[SSJ]`, finds a `null`, and then calls `null.moveRight.display();`, throwing your error. You need to populate `powerStates` before you can use the values in it.